# javascript/nodejs: get first object from JSONObject

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a JSONObject that looks like this:

```
{ a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' }
{ a: '4', b: '5', c: '6' }
```

I want to access the first object. When I write `jsonObject.a` it prints 1 AND 4. I just want the 1 and then the 4. Can you iterate through the Object somehow? The JSONObject was generated with the csvtojson package.

Comment: you mean, you have an array with objects or just more than one object in different variables?

Comment: *"When I write jsonObject.a it prints 1 AND 4"* wut..

Comment: solved it. csvtojson made 2 separate outputs, it's 2 objects

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of objects and access them by index:

```
var array = [
  { a: '1', b: '2', c: '3' },
  { a: '4', b: '5', c: '6' }
}

console.log(array[0].a);
```

Answer (score 0):

The one you wrote is not a JSON object.
They are two JSON objects. 
If you wrap them within an array, you can access the first property of the first object in this way:

`myArray[0][0]`